# Do you retain darkvision while polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, vision-and-light

If a character or monster that normally has darkvision is polymorphed into an animal that normally does not, does it still have darkvision?

Comment: I've edited out the [rules-as-written] tag (and replaced the tags with more relevant ones); it's meant to be used on "Questions that are about the logical interactions and application of the game rules, when their written form is interpreted as strictly as possible, without reference to explanations or considerations outside of the rules texts." - It's not a general tag for rules questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't retain darkvision if polymorphed into a creature without darkvision.

[*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) states:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.

A creature's senses (vision) are a part of its game statistics. Therefore, your darkvision would be replaced by the creature's normal vision.

Comment: Maybe add a note concerning *Wildshape* - you'd still lose the darkvision gained from your race, but features such as a *Warlock's* *Devil's Sight* would still apply - seeing as it's a class feature, which functions normally during *Wildshape* (but not *Polymorph*).